# AJAX Refresh or Cache Issue in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

my Problem: I have a Table that refreshes every 8 seconds via the Plugin "Tablepress Ajax Refresh". Inside that Table is an Image-Gallery which changes Images everytime after a reload (another Plugin called "random images")!

It all works perfectly when I'm logged in to wordpress. But as a non-logged-in-User the Image Gallery won't change. The Ajax Reload is still working - only the Gallery wont change.

I guess it has to do with the Ajax Hooks. But I'm really lost here and don't know how I can get it to work like it does, when I'm logged in to Wordpress. Or maybe it's a caching problem for non-logged-in-users??

In short: Ajax clears cache of the refreshed site(in this case table) only when logged in as admin on wordpress.

If it helps, this is the one and only PHP File for the used ajax-refresh-plugin:

https://gist.github.com/atreju2204/7564597

Any suggestions??

Comment: You need to use wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action for it to work for non-admin `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I already tried this. But I'm a php/js-Beginner and have no idea what to set as "my_action" and "action_callback". 

Can you maybe tell me by having a look in the PHP file?

Comment: I'm not too hot on wp which is why I didn't post as an answer but this has been answered many times over. Search more.

Comment: oh and the actual ajax reaload works fine as a non-admin!! So i think maybe some kind of an "clear cache before ajax reload"-thing is not working properly.??

Answer (score 0):

> oh and the actual ajax reaload works fine as a non-admin!! So i think maybe some kind of an "clear cache before ajax reload"-thing is not working properly

Avoid caching by making the URL unique with javascript

```
url='yourpage.php';
url = url + '?_ts=' + new Date.getTime().toString();
```

If there are already querystring vars

```
url='yourpage.php?a=b&c=d';
url = url + '&_ts=' + new Date.getTime().toString();
```

Comment: As I'm very new to this. what exactly do i need to put in the JS file when my site url is index.php for example? I've learned that JS starts with $...


Sorry if i sound extremly stupid.